# Is there a way to modify MS Office options with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office

I can additionally use powershell, the registry, or anything else that c# has access to, but the goal is to modify settings for MS Office. Specifically, these ones:

https://www.howtogeek.com/155803/how-to-change-the-default-paste-setting-in-microsoft-word-2013/

While having a work-around is great, that means I have to remember to do this on every computer I use instead of running a clean program that adjust this along with my other settings all at once (I'm writing a tool to undo annoying system defaults).

A reasonable set of defaults would probably look like this:

[image]

Bottom line, NEVER paste with formatting unless it's from and to the same document.

I'm currently using a WPF project in Visual Studio with MS Office extensions (or whatever it's called when you first install it and include the office stuff)

Comment: Looks like COM interop can help here and this is relevant option `Options.PasteFormatFromExternalSource` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.options.pasteformatfromexternalsource?view=word-pia#microsoft-office-interop-word-options-pasteformatfromexternalsource)

Comment: Boom, that might be the right track! I'll check it out, but you should post that as an answer so I can accept it if it works out.